# How to select any of that div with jQuery selector and access its parameters

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have the following HTML code which uses knockout.js to populate div's:

```
<span data-bind="foreach: $root.days">
      <div class="slider" data-bind="attr: { day: day}">
        <span data-bind="foreach: $root.segment">
          <div class='slider-segment' data-bind= "style: {left: left, 
width: width, backgroundColor: color}"></div>
          <div class='slider-button' data-bind= "style: {left: left}"></div>
        </span>
        <div class='slider-label' data-bind="text: day"></div>
      </div>
    </span>
```

This code along with ko.js creates div's that look like this in chrome's inspect mode::

```
<div class="slider" data-bind="attr: { day: day}" day = mon>
.
.
.
<div class="slider" data-bind="attr: { day: day}" day = sun>
```

This is the ko.js function:

```
self.updateclock = function() {
now = (new Date());
timenow = now.getHours() + (now.getMinutes() / 60);
today = days[now.getDay()];
self.datetime(today.toUpperCase() + " " + format_time(timenow));
console.log(today.toUpperCase() + " " + format_time(timenow));
var current_key = 0;
var sx = $(".slider[day=" + today + "]")[0].offsetLeft;
console.log(sx);
var y = $(".slider[day=" + today + "]")[0].offsetTop;
console.log(y);
var x1 = sx + slider_width * (timenow / 24.0);
console.log(x1);
var x2 = sx + slider_width * (schedule[today][current_key].start / 24.0);
console.log(x2);
var w = x1-x2;
```

I would like to select any of that div with jQuery selector and access its parameters,

I do it like this:

```
var sx = $(".slider[day=" + today + "]")[0].offsetLeft;
```

However this generates error:

> thermostat.js:105 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetLeft' of undefined
>
> at ThermostatViewModel.self.updateclock (thermostat.js:105)
>   at ThermostatViewModel.self.start (thermostat.js:90)
>   at thermostat.js:166

How to properly use jQuery selector to select the property of each of the generated div's?

Comment: What does the actual generated html look like in the page inspector?  `.slider[day=""]` is going to be looking for something that looks like `<div class="slider" day="whateverValue">`

Comment: I described it in the post, but sorry, I've typed 'editor' but meant browser inspect

Comment: If that's the case, then there is no attribute of `day` on your divs.

Comment: I had few typos yet again...teribly sorry, this is what it looks like: 

    <div class="slider" data-bind="attr: { day: day}" day = mon>
.
.
.
    <div class="slider" data-bind="attr: { day: day}" day = sun>

Comment: K, in that case you should be able to select it using the `[day="sun"]` syntax

Comment: Noup. it pops the same error. I can only select it if I explicitly add <div class="slider"  day="sun"></div> rather then generate it with knockout.js foreach. However, I need to generate it using ko.js, I then add attr day to each of the generated div, but I think I am doing something wrong with jquerry while trying to select it.

Comment: `console.log($(".slider").length)` immediately before your command and see what it logs.

Comment: console.log($(".slider").length)   logs 8

Comment: Mmmm, well, they exist then, so that possibly rules out timing issues.  Out of curiosity try changing `data-bind="attr: { day: day}"` to `data-bind="attr: { data-day: day}"` and see if that makes the inspector show you a `data-day = sun`.  If it does, then try `$('.slider').filter( it => $(it).data('day') === 'sun' )`

Comment: if I change to '<div class="slider" data-bind="attr: { dataday: day}">' it displays: '<div class="slider" data-bind="attr: { dataday: day}" dataday = "MON">'

Comment: `data-day`, not `dataday`, you may have to put quotes around it to make the `-` be allowed

Comment: What's **today**? Where does it come from? What values can it take? Your selector seems correct, so the only thing that could result in an **undefined** state if your selector doesn't find anything, and that means it is "presented" with a variable that makes the selector's resulting array empty. The **day** value is `["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"]` (I guess), so **today** should be restricted to these values only.

Comment: tried with data-day, but not sure how to log or get offsetLeft in proposed selection method?

Today is a global variable  in knockout.js part of the code : var today = days[now.getDay()];

Comment: Apparently, selectors do work, because if i put this in my html:     <div class="slider" day="sun"></div> explicitly, it gets selected and reads it's values. Problem comes when I use ko.js attr binding in foreach loop (used to generate div's) to add day="name_of_the_day" I don't know should I now use some other means of selecting those kind of div's

Comment: I have edited the question in order to include ko.js function in which selectors are being applied

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, exactly? What is the `updateclock` fuction's purpose? Whatever you're trying could probably be solved nicely with a custom binding handler, but we need a little more context.

Comment: I have days div's one below other. I want to put a slight shadow over the current day div. Shadow's length should correspond to time of day

Comment: You should not have div element inside span element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated answer

(Answer updated based on comment)

If you want to render an element only for a specific day, I would create a function on the view model:

```
function isToday(day) {
    var allDays = ['SUN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT'];
    var now = new Date(),
        timeNow = now.getHours() + (now.getMinutes() / 60),
        today = allDays[now.getDay()];

    return day === today;
}
```

And then all you have to do is use this function to show the timemarker div (using the `visible` binding) for the appropriate day.

```
<span data-bind="foreach: $root.days">
    <div class="slider">
        <span data-bind="foreach: $root.segment">
            <div class='slider-segment' data-bind= "style: {left: left, width: width, backgroundColor: color}"></div>
            <div class='slider-button' data-bind= "style: {left: left}"></div>
        </span>
        <div class='slider-label' data-bind="text: day"></div>
        <div id="timemarker" data-bind="style: {top: top, left: left, width: width}, visible: $parent.isToday(day)"></div>
    </div>
</span>
```

#### Old answer

A custom binding handler would do the trick:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.shadow = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var curDay = valueAccessor();
        var allDays = ['SUN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT'];
        var now = new Date(),
            timeNow = now.getHours() + (now.getMinutes() / 60),
            today = allDays[now.getDay()];

    if (curDay === today) {
        // this is today's div! Now you can do whatever with 'element'
    }
};
```

Apply like this:

```
<span data-bind="foreach: $root.days">
    <div class="slider" data-bind="shadow: day">
        <span data-bind="foreach: $root.segment">
            <div class='slider-segment' data-bind= "style: {left: left, width: width, backgroundColor: color}"></div>
            <div class='slider-button' data-bind= "style: {left: left}"></div>
        </span>
        <div class='slider-label' data-bind="text: day"></div>
    </div>
</span>
```

Depending on how you create the shadow, you might not even need a custom binding handler but could make it work using CSS/inline styling and the default `css` or `style` bindings.

Also, like someone else mentioned in the comments, `div` elements technically shouldn't go inside of `span` elements. Inline elements should not contain block level elements.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer. Can I use div instead of span then? Also. I render shadow like this (outside the div genrating part of the html): <div id="timemarker" data-bind= "style: {top: top, left: left, width: width}"></div>
Is it feasible to do this with custom binding then?

Comment: In that case you don't really need a custom binding handler. See my updated answer for a possible solution. And yes, you can certainly use div instead of span.